# Unity3D Html over 3D flash game

Tags: html, flash, unity-game-engine

I have 3D game made in Unity3D. After some time have been spent, it works in flash correctly.

Currently i need to find a way to display HTML content over my flash.
wmode=opaque, wmode=transparent have failed, because stage3d, which unity uses to render 3d content, requires wmode=direct.

I have tried other hacks like using iframe, but this works different in all browsers(correct behaviour only under chrome with release flash player)
Now i'm thinking about get screenshot of flash stage from action script, pass this data to javascript, render this on canvas, hide flash, and move custom HTML element over this. 
All this looks so sad, am i missing some important information?

Comment: maybe you can show a popup with fancybox, it should work

Comment: @Ruben, fancybox is nice, but it's not magic i'm looking for. It doesnt allow me to display HTML without background, right on flash. It works different in chrome/opera/ie8(in ie8 it disaply box under flash). Sure it will work if i will set opaque wmode, but i cannot due to stage3d issue.

Comment: Change the wmode using javascript when needed?

Answer (score 0):

if you use flash and want to render the scene in an canvas :).... better use only flash, don't do that :) .. and strange why it doesn't work for you because I often put a div above the flash content and it works.